# grep(),str_match() to match [DATA] string in a file and read contents below it after match is found

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Trying to read `*.BAY` file whose format is neither comma, space,tab separated. Need to find a match for string *[DATA]* and read all the contents below after the match is found.

Below is the contents of the file

> [FILEINFO]  VERSION=V4.0  FILENAME=TEST1.BAY  CREATIONTIME=2017-10-05
>    16:05:28
>
> [PARAMETER1]  TXT=SENSITIVE  Unit=LSL=-41.800000  USL=-38.300000
>
> [PARAMETER2]  TXT=HARM  Unit=LSL=-1.000000  USL=1.000000
>
> [DATA]
>   1,29,-41.699,0.075,-1.642,-97.207,55.608,0.533,165.848,0.000,0.000,60.000
>   2,29,-40.637,0.126,-1.934,-96.637,56.100,0.649,153.259,0.000,1.000,60.000
>   3,29,-40.227,0.052,-1.850,-96.231,56.104,0.548,158.987,0.000,2.000,60.000

I used below code to read the file.

```
my_txt <- paste(readLines("/TEST1.BAY)        
my_txt
```

I used `grep()` function to search *[DATA]* string. However after grep with below patter I only get `integer(empty)`.

```
my_txt <- grep("^[DATA.*]$",my_txt)
my_txt
```

Any suggestion to match the pattern and read the contents below *[DATA]*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have already read the data as a string you can remove everything till `"[DATA"]` and then use `read.csv`

```
read.csv(text = sub(".*\\[DATA\\]\\s+", "", my_txt), header = FALSE)

#  V1 V2      V3    V4     V5   ....  
#1  1 29 -41.699 0.075 -1.642   ....
```

This would give you all the data in separate columns. If you want them in one column, replace commas with newline "`\n"`

```
read.csv(text=gsub(",", "\n", sub(".*\\[DATA\\]\\s+", "", my_txt)), header = FALSE)

#         V1
#1         1
#2        29
#3   -41.699
#4     0.075
#5    -1.642
#....
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfectly. Yes I read data as string using read_file() from readr package.

Answer (score 1):

A possible method with `strsplit`

```
# read data
my_txt <- paste(readLines("clipboard"), collapse = "")      
my_txt

# split in two strings when there is "[DATA]"
my_txt <- strsplit(my_txt, "[DATA]", fixed = TRUE)

# get second string
my_txt <- my_txt[[1]][2]

# convert to vector of numeric
data <- as.numeric(strsplit(my_txt, ",")[[1]])
```